# Fit arc of spiral given segments

Tags: analysis, curves, image-processing, experimental-mathematics

I am working with a nearly Archimedian Spiral (change in radius is linear). It progresses in time, and I have taken the newest point along the spiral at .4s time intervals. (That may not be too important here though).

[image]

So with this image in mind (an (x,y) plot), I want to smooth out the curves. The kinks in the current image indicate the measurements that I took. I have the radial vectors for those points, but I want to find the radial vectors (or (x,y) coordinates) along the newly fit curve. Ultimately, I need a continuous set of data for this spiral.

Comment: The usual expression for the Archimedean spiral is $r=a+b\theta $.  If you let $\theta$ grow linearly with $t$ you seem to get what you are looking for.  Why doesn't this work?  If you just shorten the time steps the sides will get shorter.  If you make a list of points it will not be continuous, but you can make the sides very short if you use a shorter time step

Comment: @RossMillikan I think my issue with this method is resolving the constant b. I thought using a ratio of the radius change and angle change would give me b, but this b is not constant.

Comment: $b$ sets how much the spiral grows per revolution. $b=1$ makes the radius grow $2 \pi$ per revolution

Answer (score 1):

Let me consider the most general problem where you have $n$ ordered data points of coordinates $(x_i,y_i)$.

Compute for each data point the distance parameter $d_i$ defined as  $$ d_{i+1}=d_i+\sqrt{(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2+(y_{i+1}-y_i)^2} \qquad  (i=1,\cdots,n-1)$$ with $d_1=0$.

After that, for each data point $i$, $(x_i,y_i,d_i)$. So, build two parametric cubic splines, one for $x=f(d)$ and another for $y=g(d)$, $d$ varying from $0$ to $d_n$. The splines will exactly go through all the data points.

Now, for a choosen value of $d$ (which is a continuous variable), you can compute the corresponding $x$ and $y$ and get a smooth description of the whole curve.